# Maven release plugin error "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory"

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I have a maven project. When i try to release the project it gives me

**"The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory".**

Normally i run the maven commands in the project directory which includes pom.xml

Maven release command : mvn release:clean release:prepare -DreleaseVersion=1.1.5 -DdevelopmentVersion=1.1.6-SNAPSHOT -Dtag=1.1.5

```
C:\Users\sahin.atam\Desktop\milgem_epkis\src\products\common>mvn release:clean release:prepare -DreleaseVersion=1.1.5 -DdevelopmentVersion=1.1.6-SNAPSHOT -Dtag=1.1.5
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Milgem IPMS Common Modules Project
[INFO] FFDC Ospl Library
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Milgem IPMS Common Modules Project 1.1.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:clean (default-cli) @ milgem-common ---
[INFO] Cleaning up after release...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) @ milgem-common ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.next, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.branch, **\pom.xml.tag
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --username satam --password ***** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive status"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\sahin.atam\Desktop\milgem_epkis\src\products\common
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
[INFO] Transforming 'Milgem IPMS Common Modules Project'...
[INFO] Transforming 'FFDC Ospl Library'...
[INFO] Not generating release POMs
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] C:\
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 0.063 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-23T16:34:04+02:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/242M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR]
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR]
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Milgem IPMS Common Modules Project ................. FAILURE [  2.910 s]
[INFO] FFDC Ospl Library .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.101 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-23T16:34:04+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/242M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project milgem-common: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.yaltes.ipms</groupId>
    <artifactId>milgem-config</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</parent>


<groupId>com.yaltes.ipms</groupId>
<artifactId>milgem-common</artifactId>
<version>1.1.5</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>Milgem IPMS Common Modules Project</name>

<properties>
    <ipms.tagBase>milgem-common</ipms.tagBase>
    <ospl.version>6.10.0p2</ospl.version>
    <ospl_home>C:\IPMS\open-splice\Vortex_v2\Device\VortexOpenSplice\6.10.0p2\HDE\x86_64.win64</ospl_home>
</properties>


<modules>
    <module>ffdc-ospl</module>
</modules>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensplice.dds</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcpssaj</artifactId>
            <version>${ospl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<scm>
    
<connection>scm:svn:http://svn/svn/dzkk_epkis/tags/milgem_epkis/milgem- 
common/1.1.5</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn/svn/dzkk_epkis/tags/milgem_epkis/milgem-common/1.1.5</developerConnection>
</scm>
</project>
```

Comment: Please show the full pom file ...

Comment: I added pom.xml file